# install: invalid user "mysql" on Gentoo

Tags: gentoo

I just installed Gentoo 2.2 in a Mac-hosted VirtualBox.  I seeing the following snippet in /var/log/rc.log:

```
* Activating additional swap space ...
[ ok ]
* setting up tmpfiles.d entries ...
install: invalid user "mysql"
[ !! ]
* Initializing random number generator ...
[ ok ]
```

I don't have mysql installed.

What is causing the invalid user message and how do I make it go away?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was.  I had `mysql` set in the `USE` variable in `/etc/portage/make.conf` even though I hadn't installed MySQL yet.  Doing the following solved the problem:

1. Remove mysql from USE in `/etc/portage/make.conf`.
2. `emerge --update --deep --newuse @world`
3. `emerge --depclean`